# JavaScript SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, recursion, syntax

I'm learning JavaScript by reading Eloquent JavaScript.  I'm running my code on the console provided by the book's website. I'm getting a `SyntaxError : Unexpect Identifier` from the following bit of code.  Please help.

```
function absolute (n){
  if (n < 0)
    return -n;
  else
    return n;
}  

function average(x, y){
  return (x + y) / 2;
}


function isGoodEnough(x, guess){
  return (absolute(x - guess) < 0.0001);
}

function maybe(x, guess){
  if isGoodenough(x, guess){
    return guess;
  }
  else{
    return maybe(x, average(x, x/guess));
  }
}

function sqrt(x){
  return maybe(x, 1);
}
```

Comment: Does it tell you which line the Syntax Error is on?

Comment: You're missing parentheses around the `if isGoodEnough(x, guess)` in the `maybe` function.

Comment: You should use `return -1*n`, not `return -n`. Also, [JSlint](http://www.jslint.com/) is your friend.

Comment: @DesertIvy: `return -n;` is valid code.  http://jsfiddle.net/Buqh9/

Comment: This question and its answers suck... They're only useful for this very specific question. A debugging tutorial would be much more helpful to future visitors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find Javascript syntax errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120093/how-to-find-javascript-syntax-errors)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the parentheses in your `if` statement:

```
if (isGoodEnough(x, guess)) {
```

You also misspelled the function name, and that will cause a different error.

Answer (score 2):

`if isGoodenough(x, guess){` is missing the parentheses: `if(isGoodenough(x, guess)){`

Answer (score 1):

isGoodEnough is mispelled in the maybe function.

```
function maybe(x, guess){
  if isGoodenough(x, guess){
    return guess;
  }
  else{
    return maybe(x, average(x, x/guess));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is true, but misspellings will cause a ReferenceError at most, not a SyntaxError.

Comment: If fixed the brackets and the spelling error.  Now I'm exceeding the maximum call stack.  I'll just go rewrite it with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the brackets

```
 if isGoodEnough(x, guess){
    return guess;
  }
```

should be

```
 if (isGoodEnough(x, guess)){
    return guess;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around this `if` condition:

```
function maybe(x, guess) {
    if (isGoodEnough(x, guess)) {   // Note extra parentheses
        ...
```

(You've also misspelled "isGoodEnough" here.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put parantheses around the if conditions and else as well. Also use brackets to test statments after if statments. should look like

```
 function absolute (n){
  if (n < 0){
    return -n;
    }
  else {
    return n;
    }
  }  

 function average(x, y){
   return (x + y) / 2;
   }


 function isGoodEnough(x, guess){
   return (absolute(x - guess) < 0.0001);
   }

 function maybe(x, guess){
  if (isGoodEnough(x, guess)){
     return guess;
     }
  else{
     return maybe(x, average(x, x/guess));
     }
 }

  function sqrt(x){
   return maybe(x, 1);
  }
```