# if statement in ajax append block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax block that is processing a json response from an external API. I have a field for the object called status and depending on the status, I would like to display the corresponding tooltip. Currently, I am trying to do this with an if statement but but I am getting an error.

The error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

Ajax block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: "pull_overview",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        if ( data == null ) {
          $('#ajax-loader').hide()
          $('#overviewlist tbody').append("<tr><td colspan='100'><h3><center>You have no recent transactions.</center></h3></td></tr>");
        } 
        else {
          $('#ajax-loader').hide()
          $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            $('#overviewlist tbody').append("<tr><td>"    + element.name + "</td><td>" 
                                                          + element.time + "</td><td>" 
                                                          + element.type + "</td><td>"
                                                          + element.change_in_balance + "</td><td>"
                                                          + element.method + "</td><td>"
                                                          + 
                                                          if (element.status == 'New Transaction') {
                                                            "<td><button type='button' class='tooltips btn-u btn-u-xs btn-u-purple' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Your transaction is currently being processed'>Pending</button></td></tr>"
                                                          } 
          });
        }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: use `(element.status == 'New Transaction' ? "...data inside if..." : "" ;)` instead of your if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, you have a *SyntaxError*. The fixed code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pull_overview",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == null) {
            $('#ajax-loader').hide()
            $('#overviewlist tbody').append("<tr><td colspan='100'><h3><center>You have no recent transactions.</center></h3></td></tr>");
        } else {
            $('#ajax-loader').hide()
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                $('#overviewlist tbody').append("<tr><td>" + element.name + "</td><td>" + element.time + "</td><td>" + element.type + "</td><td>" + element.change_in_balance + "</td><td>" + element.method + "</td><td>" + element.status == 'New Transaction' ?
                    "<td><button type='button' class='tooltips btn-u btn-u-xs btn-u-purple' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Your transaction is currently being processed'>Pending</button></td></tr>" : "");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What is changed?

- some missing parentheses
- you cannot have `if` statement inside of a string (e.g. `"foo" + if(something) "bar"`). Use ternary operator instead: `"foo" + something ? "bar" : ""`

Useful resources:

- [Operator precedence with Javascript Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1788917/1420197)
- [How to find Javascript syntax errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2120093/1420197)
- [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6259982/1420197)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put an if statement in the middle of a string concatination in your last `append` call. do this instead

```
content = "<tr><td>" + element.name + "</td><td>" 
          + element.time + "</td><td>" 
          + element.type + "</td><td>"
          + element.change_in_balance + "</td><td>"
          + element.method + "</td><td>";
if (element.status == 'New Transaction')
    content += "<td><button type='button' class='tooltips btn-u btn-u-xs btn-u-purple' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Your transaction is currently being processed'>Pending</button></td></tr>";
$('#overviewlist tbody').append(content);
```